# Unknown Publisher warning on downloaded HTA

Tags: javascript, windows, windows-8, code-signing, hta

When starting a HTA file downloaded in a Zip, Windows prompts the "Unknown Publisher" warning (Windows 8 even a second warning). I understand that signing applications can prevent this.

How would I proceed with a HTML application, ie. an HTA file? Is there any way to avoid the warning, preferrably without changing the client´s settings?

Comment: Browsers usually flag downloaded files as untrusted. See if downloaded zip has unblock option in the bottom of its general tab of properties dialog(right click->properties). Unblocking usually avoids one of the two warning in windows 8 usually. Just a pointer.

Comment: sadly, looks like it's a per-computer setting:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/06/19/how-to-bypass-the-security-warning-unknown-publisher-with-the-checkbox-always-ask-before-opening-this-file.aspx  I've never see a signed HTA in the wild, but it might work...

Comment: Microsoft themselves should be asking this question...the Windows genuine advantage validation process on Windows 7 is asking me to download and run a .hta application, which comes up as an untrustworthy piece of code from an unknown publisher.